# How to set the position of a node related to another node in scenekit

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

How can I set the position of a node related to another node in scenekit. In realityKit we can done this using .setPosition(SIMD3<>,relativeTo:entity). But how can we do this in scenekit

Answer (score 2):

Check out [convertPosition(_:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407990-convertposition), which is a method of SCNNode in SceneKit.

It doesn't work the exact same way as setPosition, but you can get the coordinates based on other elements, so it will work for you.

For example, `item1` and `item2` have the same parent node. `item1` is at [x, y, z], and you want `item2` to be 1m above `item1`:

```swift
let pos2 = item1.convertPosition(SCNVector3(0, 1, 0), to: item2.parent)
item2.position = pos2
```

---

If you wanted more information:
This is because you want the location 1m above `item1` in its own vector space `item2` is in the space of its parent. So if it were a direct child of `item1`, you would just need to set its position to [0, 1, 0]. If you're changing scales in a deeper hierarchy then you may need to make further adjustments, but this will get you most of the way.